# Plugins only working in vimrc file. How do I fix this?

Tags: neovim

After I type `source %` in .vimrc, I can use plugins in .vimrc (If I do not type `source %` it will not work).

When I create a new file, I cannot type `source %` because it will say that it cannot open the file.

If I try to use the plugin without sourcing it does not think there are any plugins.

I just downloaded vim-plug. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Maybe you should give us more information about your `.vimrc` and I  particular how your plugins are declared. Are you using a plugin manager?

Comment: Welcome to vi SE! I would guess that your `.vimrc` is not actually found and sourced by Vim. Refer to `:h vimrc` and double check the file is in the right path and has the right name for your OS. FWIW, you can source files by name, e.g. `:source PATH/TO/.vimrc`